Why does the compute sanitizer not detect leaks in CuPy kernels?
kernel = r"""
extern "C" __global__ void entry0() {
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        malloc(16);
    return ;
}
"""

import cupy as cp
raw_module = cp.RawModule(code=kernel, backend='nvcc', enable_cooperative_groups=True)
def main():
    v1 = raw_module.get_function(f"entry0")
    v1((2,),(32,),(),shared_mem=0)

if __name__ == '__main__': print(main())

PS C:\Spiral's ML Library> compute-sanitizer --leak-check full python .\backend_tests\test2.py
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
None
========= LEAK SUMMARY: 0 bytes leaked in 0 allocations
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

Am I missing a step to make the compute-sanitizer work with CuPy? I doubt the compiler is optimizing that unfreed malloc away. I tried a similar piece of code on a C++ project, and the compute-sanitizer worked properly.
